# how to compare string with a dynamic text in java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There is a string:
"**Login *1234* has been created**"
Here 1234 is a dynamic text. 
How can I compare this entire string in one shot.

I do know of the way to do split using " "(space) and then getting into array,asserting it using regex:

assertTrue(dynamicText.substring(1, 5).equals([0-9]+));

but that takes more lines of code. I want to know if there is any efficient way of coding other than this. Thanks.

Comment: It is wierd to use an output text as input for your program to work. Don't you have the variable that contains 1234 somewhere ?

Comment: Do you just want to check of the string has a sequence of numbers in it?

Comment: I have, but I put the value here to make it clear.

Comment: @Sweeper I want to check the entire String along with the dynamic text.

Comment: If the entire string matches what is the logic of checking the dynamic part also. If you have the variable part already just create the expected string in your code and compare with the actual one.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
String expected = "Login 1234 has been created";
        if(expected.matches("Login ([0-9]+) has been created"))
        {
            System.out.println("matched");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are primarily two assertions visible with your input:

1. Asserting statics in the output

   ```
   assertTrue(dynamicText.contains("Login") && dynamicText.contains("has been created"));
   ```
2. ```
   String userInput = "1234"; 
   // if there is a dynamic variable provided as an input this has to be there in your code somewhere

   assertTrue(dynamicText.substring(1, 5).equals(userInput));
   ```

The reason that the `input` *has to be there* is otherwise you would end up reading static text from `WebElement`s found by you.

***Hence in short***

```
String expectedOutput = "Login " + userInput + " has been created.";
assertTrue("The expected output is different!", dynamicText.equals(expectedOutput));
```

Comment: How does this works when comparing the template `{"name" : "$name", "age" : "$age"}` with `{"name" : "Bob",   "age" : 47}` at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146644/compare-dynamic-xml-json-content-with-static-payload

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
if (s.matches("Login \\S+ has been created")) {
    // code here
}
```

If you need the login name, you can't use that convenience method, but have to use the `Pattern` class directly:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Login (\\S+) has been created");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
    String login = m.group(1);
    // code here
}
```